# Application crashed while initializing Fabric android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I want to read a user timeline on twitter for that I am using Fabric.On reading the official documentation for application authentication I found this method to authenticate with fabric

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(Constants.TWITTER_API_KEY, Constants.TWITTER_API_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

and getting this error

```
12-30 22:15:37.202  25440-25440/com.iifa.utsavam W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected Lcom/twitter/sdk/android/core/internal/TwitterSessionVerifier;.verifySession (Lcom/twitter/sdk/android/core/Session;)V
12-30 22:15:37.202  25440-25440/com.iifa.utsavam W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0017
12-30 22:15:37.202  25440-25440/com.iifa.utsavam W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected    Lcom/twitter/sdk/android/core/internal/TwitterSessionVerifier;.verifySession (Lcom/twitter/sdk/android/core/Session;)V
12-30 22:15:37.202  25440-25440/com.iifa.utsavam W/dalvikvm﹕ Verifier     rejected class     Lcom/twitter/sdk/android/core/internal/TwitterSessionVerifier;
12-30 22:15:37.212  25440-25440/com.iifa.utsavam D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-30 22:15:37.212  25440-25440/com.iifa.utsavam W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418038b0)
java.lang.VerifyError: com/twitter/sdk/android/core/internal/TwitterSessionVerifier
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.onPreExecute(TwitterCore.java:126)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:66)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:439)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:383)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:340)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:311)
        at com.iifa.utsavam.AuthActivity.onLoginSkip(AuthActivity.java:75)
        at com.iifa.utsavam.AuthActivity_$1.onClick(AuthActivity_.java:93)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17904)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

These are my grade files

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
```

And my app gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.linux.tweener"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.2'
compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.7'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
//    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.0.2'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
compile 'com.github.citux:datetimepicker:0.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.7'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.3.0'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.11.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;

}
}
```

Comment: are u using eclipse or studio?

Comment: Studio. I have made a dummy app and its working fine with same setup

Comment: show complete log cat

Comment: Are you using retrofit? Might be a dependency conflict.

Comment: Yup I see that......Thanks @vjdhama

Comment: Problem in retrofit, Fabric and twitter use old version of retrofit.
Just downgrade to 1.9.0 or lower - and it will work!

Comment: Major minor version compilation may cause `Verify error`

Comment: Still same error downgraded to 1.8.0

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric.

Can you paste the full error you're seeing? It seems cut off.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I have updated the error log.Can you look please into the matter.

Comment: Thanks @thestrongenough , I walked through the simple setup and it worked fine matching what you're seeing in your dummy app. What's the difference between your configurations for the two projects?

Comment: I have done the same for my dummy app and it worked before but now I have changed the gradle file with current project and now It is also crashing with same error.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I am uploading my gradle file also

Comment: You could try updating to a newer version of the gradle tools - you're on 1.2.3 and 1.5.0 is out.

Comment: @MikeBonnell but my dummy app is working fine with 1.2.3.I think there is version conflicts in the retrofit libraries.Can you please check that.

Comment: I'd recommend using version 1.9.0 of Retrofit.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I think I have got the error it is because of retrofit-gson.Can you please give me the stable version to be used with fabric.

Comment: The same one mentioned above should work.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Have you tried with above configuration. I am pretty confident it will not work .Kindly look into the matter ...problem is with gson-converter retrofit and how it could be resolved?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my earlier responses. TwitterKit doesn't support Retrofit 2.0.0-beta. Since the gson-converter is in beta1 along with the rest of Retrofit 2.0.0, we're looking into being compatible with Retrofit 2 once a stable, non-beta, version is released. Until that time, using non-beta versions of Retrofit is needed.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks for reply. Actually my application is now working with retrofit 1.8.But as I told gson converter is creating the problem. Can you tell me a way to use non beta version as I am unable to find it on retrofit documentation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @thestrongenough anytime and I don't know the answer to your second question. Perhaps someone else does though.

Comment: @MikeBonnell thank you for taking out your time and looking into my problem. But I didn't found any relevant answer anywhere finally I have to backport my application to retrofit 1.8.0 and also had to remove the gson-converter library. By the way fabric is awesome.Good work guys.

Answer (score 0):

For Use Fabric

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

        // For Simple Login:
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

        // For Simple Login as well as add crashlytics.
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig), new Crashlytics());

        // For Post Tweets
        Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new TweetComposer());
```

also u need to add permission in manifest file

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="--Add Your Key Here--" />
```

also check your Build.gradle file(app module)

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

and Build Dependency

```
// For Crashlytics
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    // For Twitter Login
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Kindly follow this.

Comment: I have all the basic stuff and I have made a dummy app which is working fine.